# What happens if range() with a for loop doesn't exactly reach the end number?

Tags: python-3.x

This is for Leetcode question 13 Roman to Integer. I have a for loop (the second one) where I increment by 2 each loop but the value of the string I am looping over is 3 in length so the loop never reaches the exact end value.

My second for loop starts at 1 for the range value and then the second time it loops it returns 1 again. I assumed it would have stopped since when it incremented by 2 the second time 1 + 2 = 3 which would be an index outside of the 3 char string "III" that is being tested. What is going on?

```
class Solution:
    def romanToInt(self, s: str) -> int:
        # dictionary of values 
        sdict = {"I":1,"V":5,"X":10,"L":50,"C":100,"D":500,"M":1000}
        scases = {"IV":4,"IX":9,"XL":50,"XC":90,"CD":400,"CM":900}
        
        if s in scases:
            return scases[s]
        else:
            fnum = 0
            for cind in range(0,len(s),2):
                print("loop1 " + str(cind))
                fullchar = None
                char1 = s[cind]
                for cind2 in range(1,len(s),2):
                    print("loop2 " + str(cind2))
                    char2 = s[cind2]
                    fullchar = char1 + char2
                    if fullchar in scases:
                        fnum += scases[fullchar]
                    else:
                        fnum += sdict[char1] + sdict[char2]
                if fullchar == None:
                    fnum += sdict[char1]
            return fnum
```

Many thanks.

Comment: General answer of questions like "what happen when ..." is "just test it!". I suggest you could try a very small piece of code to se what happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inner `for` loop is executed twice since it's inside your outer `for` loop.

To simplify, consider this:

```
while True:
    for i in range(1, 3, 2):
        print(i)
```

Would you expect the `for` loop to only be executed once?
Every time you re-enter the loop `range(1, 3, 2)` is re-evaluated and the loop happens again.

Your example simplified is this:

```
for i in range(0, 3, 2):
    print(i)
    for j in range(1, 3, 2):
        print(j)
```

It would be surprising (to me) if the inner `for` loop was only executed once seeing that the outer loop was executed twice.

It seems what you're looking for is something like `zip_longest` from the `itertools` package.

```
from itertools import zip_longest
for i, j in zip_longest(range(0, 3, 2), range(1, 3, 2)):
    print(i, j)
```

That being said, your approach will break with an input such as `'XIV'` but I'll leave that as an exercise.